# Styling shadowed elements from outer world using Stylus/WebStorm

Tags: angular, webstorm, stylus, shadow-dom, angular2viewencapsulation

In Angular 2 I am trying to style an instance of a component from the stylesheet of its container

```
<my-container>
  <my-component>
    <span>some text</span>
  </my-component>
</my-container>
```

Obviously, I have `ViewEncapsulation.None` set in `my-component.ts`.

*my-container.styl*:

```
:host /deep/ span {
  color: red;
}
```

Basically I am puzzled that with ViewEncapsulation disabled, the selector still needs `/deep/` for the span to acquire the red color styling. Other than that, I am kind of unsure what type of selector should I use, given that `/deep/` and `::shadow` are said to be deprecated. The only thing that's left on the battlefield seems to be the triple `>` combinator `>>>`.

This in turn doesn't seem to be supported/understood either by stylus or WebStorm. The effect is that reformatting code completely mangles the styling code.

Is there any other way to code the css/styl selector for my span elements than the one I am using?

**EDIT**

When trying to look into what are plans for the future, I looked into the [draft spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-scoping-1/#host-selector) - just before section 3.2.6 it says:

> **For a stylesheet** in the outer document, the selector x-foo >>> span
>   selects all three of  elements: #top, #not-top, and #nested.

But then it states:

> The shadow-piercing descendant combinator is part of the static
>   profile of Selectors, not the dynamic profile. This means that it is
>   usable in, for example, the querySelector() method, but **is invalid
>   when used in stylesheets**.

I don't get it.

Comment: To be clear the >>> works, but Webstorm and stylus don't seem to understand it right?

Comment: @oreofeolurin That's correct. Its probably **either** Webstorm or stylus. The selector works ok in the browser when I leave the code unformatted.